# Python 3 - TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

i'm currently running this as a piece of my code for an i/o stream - i'm getting the following error TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable for the print (bytest[:10]). What's the proper way run it in Python 3?

```
with open("/bin/ls", "rb") as fin: #rb as text file and location 
  buf = fin.read()
bytes = map(ord, buf)    
print (bytes[:10])
saveFile = open('exampleFile.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(bytes)
saveFile.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3 [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a generator. Try creating a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) from it first.

```
with open("/bin/ls", "rb") as fin: #rb as text file and location 
  buf = fin.read()
bytes = list(map(ord, buf))
print (bytes[:10])
saveFile = open('exampleFile.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(bytes)
saveFile.close()
```

If you think that is ugly, you can replace it with a list generator:

```
bytes = [ord(b) for f in buf]
```

Comment: You could use [**`itertools.islice`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, if you only need to read a specific slice once that may be even better.